# Why Magento ask First Name and Last Name?

Tags: attributes, customer, name

As store owner, the two name field data (First name and last name) is very inconvenience while running store.

- Most of shipping carrier I use ask only one full name data when I import shipping address. I have to merge both first and last name data as one after export shipping address. (Even a payment company ask only one full name data)
- It cause some issue when I manage or search customers with name
- I tired to get only one name data, but I got problems since magento use first name and last name differently on many ways (even in welcome message) so I give up
- As customer's view, it looks inconvenience too. Type first name and click other field and type last name instead of just type full name. (checkout is important since its related conversion rate)

I hope Magento get only one name data as store owner (I believe Magento is made for store owner too)

**Can I know at least the reason why Magento ask two name field as developer's view? Is there any benefit?**

e.g.) Top e-commerce company Amazon and ebay ask only one

This is **Amazon** New address form - Only one name field

[image]

**eBay** New address form - only one name field

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just part of Magento's architecture to use a first name and a last name.

Your question asks why this is the case. Presumably, Magento has added the `firstname` and `lastname` attributes (along with even an optional `middlename` one is defined as default but not displayed) to provide as much flexibility as possible for the merchant. This is a departure from other more established sites, as you noted, but Magento has to cater for a range of possible merchants, and tries to be as non-specific as possible.

However, like all of Magento, nothing is set in stone, and it can be changed, however this is a coding exercise, and as a result can be quite a complicated procedure. To enable this, you'd need to do a few different things. I'll try and detail the steps I'd take below.

#### 1. Add Full Name Attribute

The full name needs to be added as an attribute to a customer. You can create a module to handle this, but essentially, you'll need to run an installer script to install `fullname` as an attribute against the customer attribute set.
There are lots of useful tutorials about this around the web. [Excellence Magento has a great one](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/) (code partially shown below, edited to your requirements)

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'fullname', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Full Name',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '0',
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));
```

#### 2. Add your new attribute in your templates

You'd now need to go through and add the field for your new attribute to all relevant templates; thereby allowing the user input of it.

You can remove the First Name and Last Name fields in the process, wherever they are applicable.

#### 3. Adjust the firstname and lastname attributes

First Name and Last Name are required attributes in the database, so you won't be able to do much until you remove their `required` status from the attributes themselves.

You'll need to write a single-use script to adjust the settings; the code should resemble the following:

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('customer','firstname');
if ($attributeId) {
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attribute->setIsRequired(false)->save();
}

$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('customer','lastname');
if ($attributeId) {
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attribute->setIsRequired(false)->save();
}
```

After that, you should have successfully transferred `firstname` and `lastname` into a single `fullname` field.

If you have any existing customers, you'll be able to write a script that will combine the `firstname` and `lastname` fields into the `fullname` one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will def try it with developer. Is it possible to develop those whole process as module so I can just install then don't have to repeat when I create new store?

Comment: Yeah, you'll be able to put the attribute modification code into a Module's install script, so that it runs upon install, only once. You could then just install that module on as many systems as required.

Answer (score 0):

Simple it depends on the Magento architecture. Where Magento store "first name " or "last name" as an attribute and also "middle name" which is rarely used by the peoples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you having this scenario.
Magento has a `$customer->getName()` function for customer object which will always return complete name.
You just need to use getName() rather than getfullName() or getData('fullname').

I hope this will solve all your concerns. :)

**Can I know at least the reason why Magento ask two name field as developer's view? Is there any benefit?**

You can create fullname from first_name and last_name and you can use them separately as well but if you only have a single field for name, You can't do that. Like for frontend rendering, I would like to get greeting as `Hello Aman` rather than `Hello Aman Srivastava`.